# Geolocator gives Wrong distance using distanceBetween() Flutter with chained await async methods

Tags: flutter, dart, location

I hope all of you are safe. I have written a method to get distance between a users location, home location and the items location for an application for buying and selling. I am able to debug and get prints of the three values. When I call the method to calculate the distance, it returns bigger values thatn expected. If I replace the dynamic values with static, the method works. I am not sure where am going wrong: Help...also how do I clear the distanceList (am passing this to the Text widget. at time it will show that the items are 4096Km away when even using the values it should say like 0 meter or 120 meteres. Tried everything, nought.

```
    Future<List> calculateDistance() async {
    double itemAddressLat;
    double itemAddressLong;
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(Str.ITEMS)
        .get()
        .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) => {
              querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
                itemAddressLat =
                    double.tryParse(doc.data()[Str.ITEM_LATITUDE].toString()) ??
                        0.0;
                itemAddressLong = double.tryParse(
                        doc.data()[Str.ITEM_LONGITUDE].toString()) ??
                    0.0;

                print("ITEMS LOCATIONS....: " +
                    itemAddressLat.toString() +
                    ", " +
                    itemAddressLong.toString());
                //sample print below for itemAddressLat and itemAddressLong
                // I/flutter (14429): ITEMS LOCATIONS....: -1.2675001, 22.7865
                // I/flutter (14429): ITEMS LOCATIONS....: -1.2675001, 0.3299
                // I/flutter (14429): ITEMS LOCATIONS....: -1.278937, 2.278937
                // I/flutter (14429): ITEMS LOCATIONS....: 0.4565, 11.3422
                // I/flutter (14429): ITEMS LOCATIONS....: -1.278937, 11.278937
                // I/flutter (14429): ITEMS LOCATIONS....: -1.2675001, 32.3456
                // I/flutter (14429): ITEMS LOCATIONS....: 0.1212, 21.2222
                // I/flutter (14429): ITEMS LOCATIONS....: 0.0, 0.6765
                // I/flutter (14429): ITEMS LOCATIONS....: 1.2921, 31.8219
                // I/flutter (14429): ITEMS LOCATIONS....: 0.0, 0.0
                // I/flutter (14429): ITEMS LOCATIONS....: null, null

                //Error handling for null and empty for same fields printed above
                if (itemAddressLat.toString().isNotEmpty ||
                    itemAddressLat.toString() != null &&
                        itemAddressLong.toString().isNotEmpty ||
                    itemAddressLong != null) {
                  if (usersCurrentLocationLat.toString().isNotEmpty ||
                      usersCurrentLocationLat.toString() != null &&
                          usersCurrentLocationLong.toString().isNotEmpty ||
                      usersCurrentLocationLong.toString() != null) {
                    distance = distanceBetween(itemAddressLat, itemAddressLong,
                            usersCurrentLocationLat, usersCurrentLocationLong) /
                        1000;
                    
                    distance = distance.roundToDouble();
                    //distanceList.add(distance);
                  }
                }
                distanceList.add(distance);
              })
            });
    print(distanceList);
    return distanceList;
  }
    Future<void> setItemAndUserLocationLatLong() async {
    await getLocationFromLocationPackage();
    await getUserHomeAddress();
    print("MY LOCATION COORDINATES=========:  " +
        usersCurrentLocationLat.toString() +
        " , " +
        usersCurrentLocationLong
            .toString()); //I/flutter (14429): MY LOCATION COORDINATES=========:  0.3379671 , 32.6681845

    print("MY HOME ADDRESS COORDINATES=========:  " +
        usersCurrentLocationLatFromDb.toString() +
        " , " +
        usersCurrentLocationLongFromDb
            .toString()); //I/flutter (14429): MY HOME ADDRESS COORDINATES=========:  -1.278937 , 36.7777984

    print(distanceList); //prints I/flutter (14429): []
    print(distanceList.length); //I/flutter (14429): 0
  }

  getLocationFromLocationPackage() async {
    Location location = new Location();

    bool _serviceEnabled;
    PermissionStatus _permissionGranted;
    LocationData _locationData;

    _serviceEnabled = await location.serviceEnabled();
    if (!_serviceEnabled) {
      _serviceEnabled = await location.requestService();
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        usersCurrentLocationLat = -1.2921;
        usersCurrentLocationLong = 36.8219;
        return;
      }
    }

    _permissionGranted = await location.hasPermission();
    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) {
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }

    _locationData = await location.getLocation();
    setState(() {
      usersCurrentLocationLat = _locationData.latitude;
      usersCurrentLocationLong = _locationData.longitude;
    });

    print(usersCurrentLocationLat.toString() +
        " NEW WAY " +
        usersCurrentLocationLong.toString());
  }

  Future<void> getUserHomeAddress() async {
    var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(Str.USERS)
        .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
        .get();
    var userAddressLatFromDB = snapshot.data()[Str.LAT];
    var userAddressLongFromDB = snapshot.data()[Str.LNG];
    setState(() {
      usersCurrentLocationLatFromDb = userAddressLatFromDB;
      usersCurrentLocationLongFromDb = userAddressLongFromDB;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please refer to the following for similar issue and the approach to solve the issue if faced with similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773761/computing-inside-a-foreach-loop-of-a-querysnapshot-firebase-flutter-autogrows-li/